# How to get a constant current from a DC power supply for high voltage/current

Tags: led, current-limiting

For a project we're working on we require 4 high power LEDs, we've been using these: http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/bridgelux/BXRC-50C10K0-L-24/976-1277-ND/5180249.

We've purchased this power supply for running the lights: http://deltapsu.com/products/download/Datasheet/PMT-36V350W1AR

With our testing so far we've been using these lights using our bench power supply which allows us to set a current limit. We're quite unfamiliar with how current limiting works, so we're a bit concerned about just hooking our lights up to the power supply and letting it go nuts. Are there any off the shelf items that we would be able to put between the power supply and the lights to force a constant current, or are we being overly cautious?

Comment: Hint: I think of a current limiter or regulator as a voltage controller.

Comment: Most major distributors have current limiters if you would search, linear makes some you can parallel.

Answer (score 2):

[What you want is a constant current source.](http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en/power-supplies-external-internal-off-board/led-drivers/591038?k=constant%20current%20power%20supply&k=&pkeyword=constant%20current%20power%20supply&pv48=6997&pv48=6871&pv48=6965&pv48=5142&pv48=5392&pv48=6181&pv48=5577&pv48=5360&pv1120=621&pv1120=364&pv1120=623&pv1120=402&pv1120=378&pv1120=263&pv1120=620&pv1120=541&pv1120=565&pv1120=554&FV=fff40009%2Cfff804be&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25)
The link goes to a selection of LED Drivers at Digikey that (approximately) meet your LED requirements.
You'll need to find one that fits your needs exactly.
Other suppliers carry LED drivers as well.

You may well be better off looking in a building goods shop where they sell LED lights - they are probably cheaper than Digikey or other electronics suppliers.

Connecting the LEDs straight to a 36 Volt power supply is asking for dead LEDs.  You are not being overly cautious.  You MUST limit the current to the LEDs.

Any current limiting device will require at least a couple of Volts of headroom - the input voltage needs to be higher than the nominal voltage by at least a couple of volts.

You can build a current limiter from an LM317 or other voltage regulator.  You will have to watch out for the maximum voltage rating on the regulator, the maximum power rating of the regulator, and the voltage needed to drive the desired current through the LEDs.

Or, just buy a proper regulator (or 4, you need one for each LED) and be done with it.

---

Since your current power supply is from Delta, [here's a selection of Delta LED drivers.](http://deltapsu.com/products/led-driver?type%5B%5D=led-driver&serie%5B%5D=lne&ov%5B%5D=36%2Fnull%2Fnull%2Fnull%2Fnull%2Fnull%2Fnull&op%5B%5D=95&iv%5B%5D=100-240Vac)

---

[The LM317 datasheet has an example](http://htp://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) of a current limited regulator.  The current is set by one resistor (small value, relatively high power rating, couple of watts.)

But, it needs 3V above the nominal 36Volts for the LED to work with, so this circuit together with your 36Volt power supply won't work.

LM317 example:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you selected a power supply that provides no working headroom for your LED. It's as though you just expected to get a power supply with the voltage rating of your LED. And that's not good, because now you are left with nothing much to work from. Let me explain my reasoning here:

Your LED is specified to operate at \$38V\$, while requiring \$2.1A\$. Your power supply is rated to supply \$36V\$, with a compliance of up to \$9.7A\$. On the compliance rating, your fine. But on the voltage specification, you are under-voltage, already. (And that's just using their *typical* rating -- the actual value may vary from there.) The datasheet for the LED does suggest that it may require \$760mA\$ when operating at \$36V\$. But devices vary and there is not even close to a guarantee of that. In fact, you will have widely varying currents (and therefore widely varying light outputs) from different devices running off that voltage.

It's just not a way to go.

You need some headroom voltage. You don't have any. So it is very hard to come up with a circuit that will regulate the current into your LEDs when you have no margin to work with.

Now, let's say you wanted to actually use a standard COTS power supply like the one you do have, but wanted to add a custom, but simple and cheap, current control circuit to it for your LEDs. (Let's say you want to really just use jelly-bean everything here.) How might you proceed?

Well, you might start out with something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbabTm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But now you need to figure things out from here.

\$Q_1\$ is your main *pass* transistor here. These are dirt cheap, available everywhere in the world, supplied by many, and available in various packages and similar names if you look around. They are ubiquitous and can handle the \$< 3A\$ need, easily. \$R_1\$ is there to turn \$Q_1\$ on and to supply its needed base current. We don't yet know the value for \$V_{supply}\$ so we can't specify the value of \$R_1\$ just yet. But we can say that you may require something on the order of \$\frac{2.1A}{\beta=20} \approx 105mA\$ in order to get \$Q_1\$ sourcing \$2.1A\$ for your LED.

\$Q_2\$ is there to measure the actual current flowing and to control \$Q_1\$, accordingly. The idea here isn't too complicated, either. \$R_2\$ is in the direct path from \$Q_1\$ to your LED. So nearly all of the current used by the LED must go through \$R_2\$ (except for some bypass current via \$Q_2\$ used to control \$Q_1\$.) That current causes a voltage drop across \$R_2\$. This voltage drop will be \$V_{drop_{R_2}} = I_{LED}\cdot R_2\$. \$R_2\$ here is arranged so this voltage drop is *felt* or *observed* by \$Q_2\$ as between its emitter and base. So, with a low voltage drop \$Q_2\$ will stay OFF. When \$Q_2\$ is off, then all of the current through \$R_1\$ will feed the base of \$Q_1\$, turning it *hard-on* and supplying lots of current through \$R_2\$ and into your LED. So, technically, we really don't want \$Q_2\$ to be OFF. We want it to be measuring current and siphoning away base current from \$Q_1\$ -- just enough to get things right. Roughly speaking, \$Q_2\$ will have a "turn on" voltage of about \$700mV\$ in normal (low current) operation. But we are talking here about hundreds of mA, not tens of mA. It's time to pause for a moment and discuss those currents now.

We know we will need about \$110mA\$ base drive for \$Q_1\$. But let's give it more than enough. Let's arrange for \$200mA\$ to drive \$Q_1\$ and plan on having \$Q_2\$ divert away whatever amount is in excess of the required amount. This means \$Q_2\$ will be expected to pull away about \$100mA\$. So we can expect \$V_{BE_{Q_2}} = 700mV + 60mV\cdot log10\left(\frac{100mA}{4mA}\right) \approx 800mV\$. So \$R_2 = \frac{800mV}{2.1A} \approx 0.38\Omega\$. Make that a standard \$0.39\Omega\$ resistor value. Power in it will be under \$2W\$, so pick out a \$5W\$ resistor for that. Now we have an estimated value for \$R_2\$.

Let's look at the schematic again:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWctWh.png)</sup>

We need to find the value of \$V_x\$ there. Or estimate a reasoned value for it. From the 2n3055 datasheet from OnSemi I see that at \$4A\$ collector current (not too far from where you want to be), the worst case is \$V_{BE} = 1.5V\$. It may be better than that, and probably will be. But we have to plan for the worst case. So let's set \$V_x = 38.8V + 1.5V = 40.3V\$.

Now, also from the datasheet I know that they specify a minimum \$\beta = 20\$ also when \$I_C=4A\$. I used that value above. So that's good. But also, that \$\beta=20\$ is for the case where \$V_{CE} = 4V\$. So we need to have a power supply rail that is \$V_{supply} \ge \left(38.8 + 4V = 42.8V\right)\$.

So now here we are. You can see why you need some headroom and that you need to get a power supply that is at least \$43V\$ or so. But you need to go search and see what you can find there.

Higher voltages will drop more volts across \$Q_1\$ and \$R_1\$ and heat them up. (We haven't even figured out what \$Q_2\$ will dissipate, yet.) So you don't want to just get some *big iron* here. Perhaps \$48V\$ might be a standard value you could find. But that's a bit high. Perhaps \$45V\$? I honestly don't know.

Let's say you are stuck getting a \$48V\$ supply. Here is the final circuit then:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2futYYo.png)</sup>

The actual operating points will vary by the transistors you use. And that means the actual dissipation will vary some. The resistors are over-specified, though, so even if \$Q_1\$ doesn't need that high of a \$V_{BE}\$ (and it won't), \$R_1\$ will still be fine using \$5W\$. So it is safe to use \$5W\$ types. And the BJT dissipations are close enough that I don't think you'll go wrong with those estimates for power. The 2N3055 will definitely need a heat sink. I didn't find a thermal resistance on OnSemi's datasheet for junction-to-air. But I'd heat-sink the thing at \$20W\$ dissipation.

Note that I computed \$R_1 = \frac{48V - 40.3V}{200mA} = 38.5\Omega\$ and rounded that up to a standard value. A smaller value will just mean that \$Q_2\$ needs to pull away more current. A larger value will leave you with less to pull away, but risks not providing enough for \$Q_1\$ over variations of parts. So I wouldn't use a larger value than that.

The above is just for illustration purposes. (For example, you might try and account for the predicted bypass current via \$Q_2\$, accounting for it when estimating the desired current through \$R_2\$. Or you might design you want an adjustable current, within some reasoned limitations, which would probably need something extra to avoid finding a \$5W\$ potentiometer.)  But it does show how you might turn a standard power supply into a current supply for your needs, using dirt cheap components. It also shows you just how much heat you will be producing there, too. A lower valued power supply would save a lot of that heat. But not all of it. No matter what, you need some headroom and at \$2.1A\$ into your LED, that means there will be some wasted power.

Answer (score 0):

LM317HV could deal with the voltage.  Issue is 1) high cost dedicated unit, 2) lower cost linear (but less efficient) 3) your design using non-linear components (charge pumps, etc.) which will be more complicated.

The trick, like JRE shows, is to use a linear regulator in an unconventional way, so it acts as a current source.  Only problem is the voltage loss in the unit and through the resistor (which should be large enough to handle the current, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

The LM317 is not really beefy enough, and your existing 36V power supply isn't quite right. The nominal Vf voltage of the LEDs is slightly higher than 36V. What you want for optimal drive is something more like [this](http://www.dx.com/p/2a-70w-power-constant-current-source-led-driver-85-265v-54004#reviews).

If you're prepared to have not quite maximum brightness, and continue using your 36V supply, get some 0.5ohm 3W[resistors](http://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/ohmite/53JR50E/53JR50E-ND/5050018). Those should have enough power dissipation to survive, although they will get warm. You want one or two in series with each LED. Try with one, measure the voltage across it; if it's less than 1V you don't need to add another one.